# e4 dependency reinjection order: field vs. method

Tags: dependency-injection, e4

I was quite surprised to see that there is no deterministic behavior for the order in which objects get reinjected.

```
public class Test {
    @Inject private Boolean testBool;  

    @Inject
    public void checkNewObject(Boolean testBoolNew) {
        if (!testBoolNew.equals(this.testBool)) {
            System.out.println("Out of sync!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("In sync!");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I use the class:

```
context.set(Boolean.class, new Boolean(true));
Test test = ContextInjectionFactory.make(Test.class, context);
context.set(Boolean.class, new Boolean(false));
```

So, sometimes I get the output:

```
In sync!
In sync!
```

And sometimes I get:

```
In sync!
Out of sync!
```

Is this really non deterministic or am I just overseeing something?

Comment: Show us how you can testing this.

Comment: Well, I just quickly tested it by hand. If this is important, I can write something.

Comment: How you use the class is very important. For a start, there is no way that dependency injection will ever be done on the `checkNewObject` method since the only way to do injection on a method is using an annotation such as @Execute

Comment: Where are you calling `checkNewObject`?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Did you try it without the @Optional annotations?

Comment: Looking at the `EclipseContext` source I think this is because the values to reinject are in a `HashMap` so the order in which they are reinjected depends on a hash code which make the order unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation clearly states that the injection order should be:

1. Constructor injection: the public or protected constructor annotated with `@Inject` with the greatest number of resolvable arguments is selected
2. Field injection: values are injected into fields annotated with `@Inject` and that have a satisfying type
3. Method injection: values are injected into methods annotated with `@Inject` and that have satisfying arguments

See: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Dependency_Injection#Injection_Order

I'm not sure, why this doesn't work as expected in your case.

- How is `equals()` implemented in `MyContent`?
- Is `MyContent` annotated with `@Creatable` and or `@Singleton`?

As a side note: Is this a practical or just an academic problem? Why is it necessary to inject the same instance into a field and into a method on the same target-instance? If you want to have a field variable to cache the value, you can set this from the method.

If you feel this is a bug, please file it here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform

Comment: You are right, the first injection follows the order: field and then method. I edited my test which shows this behavior. The unspecified order only applies for the reinjection.